# Using system env vars in vscode settings

Tags: visual-studio-code, environment-variables

Is it possible to use system wide env vars like $env:JAVA_HOME or $env:ANDROID_HOME in VSCcode `settings.json`. It seems like VSCode doesn't recognize any variable beyond predefined ones. I'm trying to set `java.home` for java extension pack in `settings.json`.

OS: Windows 10
vscode 1.52.0

Answer (score 0):

According to the extension readme page, if you have set the JAVA_HOME env variable, it should be automatically recognized by the extension: https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java#java-tooling-jdk

Comment: JAVA_HOME is set, but not picked by the extension.

Comment: Are you using JDK 8? The extension requires at least JDK1 to launch.

Comment: This is the output of `java -version
openjdk version "15.0.1" 2020-10-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 15.0.1+9-18)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 15.0.1+9-18, mixed mode, sharing)`

Comment: Ah, I suddenly realized that maybe what you mean is set the `java.home` to `$env:JAVA_HOME`. As far as I know, it's not possible now. But since you have already set the JAVA_HOME env variable to JDK 15. You can simply remove the line containing `java.home` in your settings.json.

Comment: Yeah I did that but `JAVA_HOME` env var is not picked by the java extension and it asks me to set `java.home` in the `settings.json`.  So I placed the absolute path to java SDK directory there. Not a big deal but you know when you setup a multi language environment for developing having all the directories and paths in env vars make things more robust.